# Add_action not calling callback function

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, callbacks

I am currently trying to build a plugin for wordpress to build a settings page.
But for some reason when I use `add_action("admin_init", array(class_object, 'function_name'))` it will run the add_action function but won't get to the callback.
It just skips it.

I have tried making a test class with 1 function in it the same way as the main class and that does work.
So I am doing something different somewhere but I don't know what.

here is the code.
I have split the code over 3 different files and I will post it in order of including the files.

**Index file for the plugin**

```
include('admin/options.php');


function social_share_menu_item() {
    add_submenu_page("options-general.php", "Social Share", "Social Share", "manage_options", "social-share", 'socialShareOptions');
}
add_action("admin_menu", "social_share_menu_item");

...
```

**options.php**

```
include_once('settings/SocialOptions.class.php');

function socialShareOptions(){

    $options = array(
        array(
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'name'  => 'social-share-facebook',
            'value' => 1,
            'title' => 'Show Facebook '
        ),
        array(
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'name'  => 'social-share-twitter',
            'value' => 1,
            'title' => 'Show Twitter'
        ),
        array(
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'name'  => 'social-share-instagram',
            'value' => 1,
            'title' => 'Show instagram'
        )
    );

    $socialOptions = new SocialOptions($options);
    $socialOptions->buildSettingsPage();
    add_action("admin_init", array($socialOptions, 'setOptions') );
}
```

**SocialOptions.class.php**

```
class SocialOptions {

    private $_optionsArray;

    function __construct( $options = array() ) {

        $this->_optionsArray = $options;

    }

    public function setOptions() {

        add_settings_section("social_share_config_section", "", null, "social-share");

        foreach ( $this->_optionsArray as $option) {
            add_settings_field("social-share-facebook", $option['title'], array($this, 'option'), "social-share", "social_share_config_section", $option);
        }
        foreach ( $this->_optionsArray as $option) {
            register_setting("social_share_config_section", $option['name']);
        }
    }

    public function option( $fieldData ){
        ?>
        <input type="<?php echo $fieldData['type'] ?> " name="<?php echo $fieldData['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $fieldData['value'] ?>"<?php checked(1, get_option($fieldData['name']), true)?> /><?php echo $fieldData['title'] ?>
        <?php
    }


    public function buildSettingsPage() {

        $html = '<div class="wrap social-admin-style">

                    <div class="title">
                        <h1>Social Sharing Options</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="main-content">

                        <form method="post" action="options.php">

                            ' . settings_fields("social_share_config_section") . ' 

                            ' . do_settings_sections("social-share") . '

                            '. submit_button() . '

                        </form>

                    </div>

                </div>';

        echo $html;

    }


}
```

As state before when debugging the code I see that the add_action function runs but at some point it just skips tot the end of the function and never enters the setOptions method.

when I create the following it works fine:

**options.php**

```
include_once('settings/SocialOptions.class.php');

class Test {
    function testing(){
     return 'nothing';
    }
}

function socialShareOptions(){

    $options = array(
        ...
    );

    $socialOptions = new SocialOptions($options);
    $socialOptions->buildSettingsPage();

    /*NOTE THIS PART*/
    $test = new Test();
    add_action("admin_init", array($test, 'testing') );
}
```

This will, in debug, run just fine.
That is why I don't get why the other method isn't working.

**Additional information**

*tipped by B. Schuiling*
In de php error logs I don't get any kind of error.

Hope you guys can help.
And thanks for taking the time reading this.
IF you need any more info please let me know.

**EDIT**
Though the original answer wasn't what the fix was I would like you all to refer to the asnwer by B. Schuiling.
In the comments he explained that the add_action was called to late and therefore wasn't run.

below is the altered options.php page.(i left the obviouse code out to make it shourter)

**ps** though this does work I am going to change the code to a singleton way.
This also based on the link that B. Schuiling posted in the comments on his own answer below.

Notice that the options array and the instatiation of the class is now outside the socialShareOptions function.

```
include_once('settings/SocialOptions.class.php');

$options = array(
    ...
    )
);
$socialOptions = new SocialOptions($options);
add_action("admin_init", array($socialOptions, 'setOptions'));

function socialShareOptions(){
    global $socialOptions;

    $socialOptions->buildSettingsPage();
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obivous, so I'd personally go look at `WP_Hook::apply_filters` (class-wp-hook.php) and start to debug there.

Comment: @janh thank you for the tip. Going to look at that right away.

Comment: Add a debugging point inside `setOptions()` or add a `die()` inside `setOptions()` to test if the method is really getting called or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your class, your function is called 'public function setOption()' not setOptionS .  Check your error log for this kind of issues.

Also in your code I don't see the function 'socialShareOptions' actually being called anywhere.

Comment: I can give you de error of the setOptions. This is something I typed in wrong when I was writing the question. in my code it is correct and it is still not working. ps. i will add this to the answer but php and apache error logs give me no errors what so ever.

The other point you are making is you probably not looking at the code well enough. check the first code and scroll all the way to the right. There you can see the function being linked to the sub_menu_page function

Comment: Ah right. So first you hook  the menu page with 'admin_menu' link and then you try to hook these options with admin_init. That's not going to work since admin_init is earlier in the list than admin_menu, so it will not fire.

You need to separate these two functions basically.

Comment: ah ok that sounds logical. I'll be trying that. thanks for taking a look at it again :)

Comment: If you want to do it class based it's often better to just init the class without hooks ( aka very early ) and in the construct add all the hook you need, instead of making this kind of hard-to-understand chains.

Very useful is this approach - https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-in-wordpress-the-singleton-pattern--wp-31621

Comment: thanks for the link. will definitely read it and see how I can / will use that.

Comment: Just read the link you adviced and I have to say that that would indeed have a lot more advantages than what I do know.
Thank you for pointing me in that direction.